# Conditional Formatting with VLOOKUP formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I enter this formula into a cell I get the desired boolean value:

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(MID(C5;1;FIND(" -";C5)));fb_accs;9)<>"-"
```

First I'm extracting  the ID value from a cell mixed with text. And then checking if the 9th column for that row in particular in the `fb_accs` table in another sheet has no `-` in it.

However, when I copy that exact same formula and apply with conditional formatting to 1 column of the current sheet (range `=$C$3:$C$10`) it gives me an error saying:

> There's a problem with this formula.

What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `FIND(" -";C5)-1` ?

Comment: The VALUE() gets rid of the trailing space so it does work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use INDIRECT when referring to a table in a conditional format formula

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(MID(C5,1,FIND(" -",C5))),INDIRECT("fb_accs"),9)<>"-"
```

See [this article](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/10/15/how-to-use-a-table-name-in-data-validation-lists-and-conditional-formatting-formulas/)

Comment: This seems to be it. Thank you very much, even though my version uses semi-colons.

Comment: Good, apologies for the different locale setting.